# Weather layer for google maps not showing up for different cities?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, weather

I am trying to setup google maps with weather + cloud layer using the gmaps api. However it is not showing up for my city.

Is it just me or the weather layer is not displaying for other cities than the default/provided in the gmaps api (Vancouver)

http://jsfiddle.net/AzriAhmad/jzfuA/1/  (Vancouver)

```
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 12,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.265984, -123.127491),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Problem: As soon as I change the coords, the layer doesn't show up..

http://jsfiddle.net/AzriAhmad/ABa2q/1/ (New York)

```
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 12,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7142700 , -74.0059700),

 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Tried changing zoom but it didn't change anything from my side..

Edit: Fixed links

Comment: I checked both fiddles and I don't see any problems with the weather or cloud layers. Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing so we can better understand your problem (if indeed there is a problem.)

Comment: @vape [NY SS](http://postimg.org/image/pbu66lav1/);
[Vancouver SS](http://postimg.org/image/hlqihjrer/)
Basically I want that weather blob to show in for other cities..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there appears to be no error showing in examples

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. [This is what I see (SS)](http://i.imgur.com/wQz6SVW.jpg). I see the weather layer on all zoom levels. The cloud layer appears above zoom level 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was cached issues with my MacBook.